# Some questions about Hitchin's self-duality paper

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, principal-bundles

I am reading [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.557.2243) (*The self-duality equations on a Riemann surface* by N. Hitchin; DOI: [10.1112/plms/s3-55.1.59](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-55.1.59)), and I don't understand a few things in page 67. In proof of Theorem 2.1 after Equation 2.4, he gives the relation for $F(B)s$ as

$$F(B)s=F(A)s-(\deg L)\omega s+ \frac12 \deg(∧^2V)\omega s.$$

In the proof, he obtains a connection $B$ on $L^*V$ using a connection $A$ on $V$, and a connection with curvature $(\deg L)\omega$. I am thinking of $L^*V$ as a pull back of $V$, or am I wrong? If I understand what is the explicit form of this connection, I may get the curvature $F(B)$, and eventually above relation. Or is there any other way to get the above result?

I tried a lot but couldn't understand how he obtains the result above for $F(B)s$. This formula is very essential in the proof, because he uses this information in Theorem 2.1 to give a condition for stability that is discussed in the third section of the paper.
I will be very glad if somebody could explain me how to derive this result.

I have another small question which maybe related to the above question:
Initially in the top of page 67 he says "Fixing a connection $A_0$ on $∧^2V$, we find that a connection $A$ on $P$ lifts to $\tilde{P}$  whose curvature is $F(A)+1/2F(A_0)1$". Here I don't see how he can get this curvature for the lift. I was thinking, maybe he uses this curvature to find the above formula. Can someone elaborates on this one as well?

I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: $L$ is a holomorphic line subbundle of $V$, and the holomorphic inclusion $L\to V$ is the same as a holomorphic section $s$ of $L^*V$ without zeros. A connection on $L$ induces a connection on its dual $L^*,$ and together with the connection $A$ on $V$ you obtain the product connection whose curvature is given by the first equation in your question.

Comment: @Sebastian, Thanks for the hint! There is extra term in curvature, +1/2 deg(Λ^2V)ωs. How can I get that? Also can you please elaborate on the connection of the product?

Comment: The tensor product of two connections is just defined in a way that makes the Leibnizrule work: $\nabla\otimes\tilde\nabla (s\otimes t)=(\nabla s)\otimes t+s\otimes (\tilde\nabla t)$, and there is a simple formula for the curvature of a tensor product connection which you obtain by differentiating twice ( you can also  find this in most textbooks on the topic).

Comment: The extra term in curvature is due to the assumption that the $SO(3)$-bundle $P$does not admit a lift to a $SU(2)$-bundle as $w_2(P)\neq0.$ If you prefer to think about vector bundles think of the associated real rank 3 vector bundle with metric. There is a topological invariant (over the compact surface) which tells you wether the rank 3 bundle is the skew-hermitian endomorphism bundle of a unitary rank 2 bundle with trivial determinant $w_2(P)=0$), or not ($w_2(P)\neq0$). This is analogous to the theory of $Spin^{\mathbb C}$ structures but for general principal and vector bundles.

Comment: In the case $w_2\neq0$, there exist a hermitian rank 2 vector bundle $V$ whose determinant bundle has non-zero degree. Fixing the connection on the determinant bundle, the connection $A$ on $P$ uniquely determines a connection on $V$ whose curvature satisfies the formula in the first paragraph of page 67 in Hitchin's self-duality paper.

Comment: @Sebastian: Thanks for our help! they were very helpful. I tried to use this information and derive the formula for F(B)s mentioned above. I am writing that as an answer, and I would be happy if you take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I just have a few comments which would hopefully clarify a few points in the above discussion.

Consider the natural projection (a Lie group homomorphism) $p: U(2) \to U(2)/Z(U(2)) \simeq SU(2)/\{\pm \mathbf{1}\} \simeq SO(3)$. The kernel is $Z(U(2)) \simeq U(1)$, so we have a short exact sequence:
$$ 1 \to U(1) \to U(2) \to SO(3) \to 1. $$
Given a principal $SO(3)$ bundle, say $P$, on $M$, there is an obstruction for the existence of a principal $U(2)$ bundle $\hat{P}$ which maps onto $P$ using the above projection from $U(2)$ to $SO(3)$, which lives in $H^2(M, U(1))$, using Cech cohomology.

But I think that $H^2(M, U(1))$ itself vanishes because $M$ is complex 1-dimensional (can someone please confirm this in the comments?). As a result, for any principal $SO(3)$ bundle $P$, there always exists a principal $U(2)$ bundle $\hat{P}$ which projects onto $P$ using the projection $U(2) \to SO(3)$.

At the level of Lie algebras, we have that
$$\frak{u}(2) = \frak{so}(3) \oplus \mathbb{R}\mathbf{1},$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix. With formulas, this is given by
$$ x = (x - \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(x) \mathbf{1}) + \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}(x) \mathbf{1}.$$
It is the decomposition of an element $x \in \mathfrak{u}(2)$ as a trace-free part plus a pure trace part.

Note that associated to $\hat{P}$ is a rank $2$ complex bundle $V$. I claim that a connection $A$ on $P$ and a connection $A_0$ on $\Lambda^2 V$ together determine a connection on $P$.

If we denote the natural bundle map $\hat{P} \to P$ by $f$, then $f^*(A)$ is itself a connection on $\hat{P}$, but it can be shown that the trace of its curvature vanishes pointwise on $M$. Indeed, its curvature is a $2$-form on $M$ with values in the trace-free part of $\hat{P}$ (refer to the above decomposition of $\mathfrak{u}(2)$).

Consider the determinant map
$$ \operatorname{det}: U(2) \to U(1). $$
This can be thought of as mapping a $g \in U(2)$ to $\Lambda^2 g$, which is a unitary map from $\Lambda^2 \mathbb{C}^2$ to itself.

At the level of principal bundles, this induces a map from $\hat{P}$ to the bundle of unitary maps from $\Lambda^2 V$ to itself. The induced hermitian inner product on $\Lambda^2 V$, coming from the hermitian inner product on $V$, determines a reduction of the group of the corresponding principal bundle from $\mathbb{C}^*$ to $U(1)$. Let us denote the resulting principal $U(1)$ bundle by $Q$, say.

A connection $A_0$ on $\Lambda^2 V$ determines a connection on $Q$, which we will also denote by $A_0$, which then determines a connection on the (trivial) line bundle $\operatorname{End}(\Lambda^2 V)$. The latter connection is associated to a connection on the bundle of unitary maps from $\Lambda^2 V$ to itself. The latter connection pulls back to a connection on $\hat{P}$ using the determinant map described previously. Let us denote this connection, by abuse of notation, by $\operatorname{det}^*(A_0)$. Note that the curvature of this connection is pointwise pure trace, with respect to the above decomposition of $\mathfrak{u}(2)$.

Given a choice of a connection $A$ on $P$ and $A_0$ on $\Lambda^2 V$, we thus see that
$$ f^*(A) + \operatorname{det}^*(A_0) $$
is a connection on $\hat{P}$, whose curvature is
$$ F(A) + \frac{1}{2} F(A_0) \mathbf{1},$$
where $F(A)$, respectively $F(A_0)$, denotes the curvature of $A$, respectively $A_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Using your connection for the tensor product, we can find the curvature as

$$F_{\nabla\otimes\bar{\nabla}}(s_1\otimes s_2) =\nabla\otimes\bar{\nabla}\big(\nabla\otimes\bar{\nabla}(s_1\otimes s_2)\big)=\nabla\otimes\bar{\nabla}\big(\nabla(s_1)\otimes s_2
+s_1\otimes \bar{\nabla}(s_2)\big)=\nabla^{2}(s_1)\otimes s_2
-\nabla(s_1)\otimes \bar{\nabla} (s_2)+\nabla(s_1)\otimes \bar{\nabla} (s_2)+s_1\otimes \bar{\nabla}^{2}(s_2)\\= \nabla^{2}(s_1)\otimes s_2+s_1\otimes \bar{\nabla}^{2}(s_2)$$
the minus signs appears because $\nabla(s_1)\otimes s_2$ is (1,0) form.

Next we notice that $A_0$ is a fixed connection on $\wedge^2 V$ and on $V$ we have the connection $A+A_0$.Thus, the covariant derivative for connection $A_0+A$ is given by $d_{A+A_0}=d+A+A_0$, so the curvature on $V$ would be 
$$F_{A+A_0}= d^2_{A+A_0}=dA+A\wedge A+A_0\wedge A_0\\=dA+A\wedge A+\frac{1}{2}[A_0,A_0]$$

Defining $F(A):=dA+A\wedge A$ and $F(A_0):=[A_0,A_0]$, we get the curvature on $V$ according to $F(A)+\frac{1}{2}F(A_0)$ (This is the equation given in the first paragraph of page 67) Is this derivation of $F(A)+\frac{1}{2}F(A_0)$ correct?

Furthermore, since $\wedge^2 V$ is a line bundle embedded in $V$, its curvature has the form $F(A_0)=deg(\wedge^2 V)\omega$ where $\omega$ is a positive form.

So now we have 
$$F_{B}(s_1\otimes s_2)=F(V)(s_1)\otimes s_2+s_1\otimes F(L^*)(s_2)\\=(F(A)+\frac{1}{2}deg(\wedge^2 V)\omega)s_1\otimes s_2+s_1\otimes(-(deg L)\omega) s_2 \\=F(A)(s_1\otimes s_2)+\frac{1}{2}deg(\wedge^2 V)\omega (s_1\otimes s_2) - (deg L)\omega(s_1\otimes s_2)$$

Above, I used the fact that for a line bundle $L$ with some connection, the curvature is given by $(deg L)\omega$ where $\omega$ is a positive form. The minus sign is because we look at the dual space, $L^*$.

Here, I assume that in paper the section $s\in \Omega^0(M, L^*\otimes V)$ must be of the form $s:=s_1\otimes s_2$. Am I right?

If you see any errors/problems with my computations, please let me know. I will be very thankful for that!

Comment: Your computation of the curvature of the product connection is right. The remaining part does not work, for example how do you add connections on $V$ and on $\Lambda^2V.$

Comment: Okay. I didn't know that. I am new to the subject, do you recommend any book so that I can learn a similar type of arguments about connections.

Comment: You could read Nicolaesuc's 'Notes on Seiberg-Witten equations', in particular $\S 1.3$.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I will check it out.

Comment: I think the remaining part you need to clear your confusion has to do with decomposing $\mathfrak{u}(2) \simeq \mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathbb{R}$, by mapping $x$ to $(x - \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(x)\mathbf{1}, \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(x))$. I may write more details later if someone requests...

Comment: I edited my previous answer. I hope that it clarifies the remaining points in the above discussion!